# python dataframe rows: if value at row+n > value at row, set variable to A

Tags: python, pandas, label

I am working with a pandas dataframe. I trying to create a new column, data['Labels'], which contains labels determined by the change in value between row i and row i+n in column data['diff'], for the entire length of the dataframe.

I imagine something of the following, however this is returning me errors:

```
for i in range(len(data['diff'])-1):
    data.loc[data['diff'][i] >= data['diff'][i+n], 'Labels'] = 'A'
    data.loc[data['diff'][i] < data['diff'][i+n], 'Labels'] = 'B'
```

example output:

```
index diff    label
9     117.32   B
10    108.32   A
11    125.36   A 
12    127.36   A
13    139.28   A
14    141.22   A
15    147.89   A
16    153.89   B
17    153.89   B
18    156.87   B
19    168.84   B
20    161.04   B
21    172.04   B
24    175.16   B
22    164.04   B
23    164.16   B
27    175.16   B
25    149.16   A
```

Comment: you can just do `data['Labels'] = np.where(data['diff'] >= data['diff'].shift(), 'A', 'B')`

Comment: Hi Ed,
Thanks! This works great for comparing i and i+1, however I just realized I would like the shift to also include the  possibility that data['diff'][i] >= data['diff][i+n]. Basically, I want to create a label depending on changes anywhere further in the data['diff'] timeseries.

Comment: Changing your requirements is bad form for SO, also your comment requires further explanation is `n` fixed? or do you want to compare `i` against a range of rows?

Comment: IIUC then just pass `n` to `shift` e.g. `.shift(n)`

Comment: Apologies, I am new to SO. I have changed the title of the question to be relevant. 

n is not fixed, however it must be larger than i. So yes, I am wanting to compare data['diff'][i] against the values of any of the following rows.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You should provide an example with your desired output.

Comment: Did my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to set the label to `A` if there is a higher value in any of the following rows.

You can get the maximum value of the remaining rows with `cummax`. However, you need to revert the index first, otherwise `cummax` will return the maximum of the preceding rows. You you can do that with `.iloc[::-1]`:

```
df['following_max'] = df['diff'].iloc[::-1].cummax().iloc[::-1]
```

Then apply the label `A` whenever the following max is greater than the current value:

```
df['Labels'] = np.where(df['diff'] < df['following_max'], 'A', 'B')
```